# Android EditText cursor "ghosts"

Tags: android, android-edittext

I am only an occasional Android programmer and can't seem to find an answer to this one.  I am guessing I set something up wrong.  My app works fine in the emulator, but when I move to a device, the

t|e|x|t|l|o|o|k|s|l|i|k|e|t|h|i|s|

[image]

when I type.  My code is as follows, its pretty simple at this point...

**EditText in xml**

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/server_username"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="text" />
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final Button clickButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.save_button);
    final EditText serverUrl = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.server_url);
    final EditText serverUsername = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.server_username);
    final EditText serverPassword = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.server_password);


    clickButton.setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    String url = serverUrl.getText().toString();

                    String username = serverUsername.getText().toString();

                    String password = serverPassword.getText().toString();

                    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

                    values.put(CredentialsProvider.SERVERURL, url);

                    values.put(CredentialsProvider.USERNAME, username);

                    values.put(CredentialsProvider.PASSWORD, password);

                    getContentResolver().update(
                    CredentialsProvider.CONTENT_URI, values, null, null);

                }
     });

      String URL = "content://com.dont.touch.jobus.rum/credentials/1";
      Uri creds = Uri.parse(URL);
      Cursor c =getContentResolver().query(creds, null, null, null, "username");
      if (c.moveToPosition(0)) {
          serverUrl.setText(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex( CredentialsProvider.SERVERURL)));
          serverUsername.setText(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex( CredentialsProvider.USERNAME)));
         serverPassword.setText(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex( CredentialsProvider.PASSWORD)));

      } else {
          ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

          values.put(CredentialsProvider.SERVERURL, 
                  "not configured");

          values.put(CredentialsProvider.USERNAME, 
                  "not configured");

          values.put(CredentialsProvider.PASSWORD, 
                  "not configured");

          getContentResolver().insert(
                  CredentialsProvider.CONTENT_URI, values);
      }
}

@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);

}
```

}

Comment: please review that you don't have textWatchers or maskfilters on your editText if so, please review it carefully... also would be good if you post the code that interacts with the EditText and the EditText xml

Comment: Can you show how you declare the TextBox on the XML file?

Comment: after commenting out all references to the edittext fields in my activity.java, the problem persists.

Comment: Have you tried cleaning and rebuilding your app?

Comment: Yes, I have cleaned and rebuilt, reloaded with f5 and even restarted eclipse, no change

Comment: Can you try it on another device? Also try removing all the String/URL/Cursor stuff, and see if the problem persists. If it does the problem is probably in that block of code and then we can look deeper into it.

Comment: Commented out everything in mainactivity.java but the bare minimum to run and it still does it on multiple devices and now the emulator.  I have even started from scratch with a new project.