# Android EditText Glitches

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

I have a simple app with 3 edittext fields.  When I type, the t|e|x|t|l|o|o|k|s|l|i|k|t|h|i|s.  In my mainactivity.java, i have commented out ALL references to those fields and the problem persists.  I can't seem to find anything about it and I am at a loss as I do Android very occasionally.

Yes, I asked this question too, unsure what is appropriate as far as reposting.

[Android EditText cursor "ghosts"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23765181/android-edittext-cursor-ghosts)

my activitymain.xml looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:gravity="top"
android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
android:layout_marginLeft="40dp">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/server_url"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/server_url"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="@string/server_hint"
    android:inputType="textUri" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/server_username"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/server_username"
    android:hint="@string/server_hint"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="text" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/server_password"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/server_password"
    android:hint="@string/server_hint"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textPassword" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/save_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/save_button" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Yes, reposting is bad. Edit your OP to make it more clear. After reading both, I am still confused on what you are saying.

Comment: added a picture of the results to the other post.  This is with no code interacting with the edittext field whatsoever.